# Get html code of current page and pass it in a variable with post method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to capture and pass with method `POST` the current HTML code of a page. I'm using:

```
var html_document = document.documentElement.innerHTML;

document.body.innerHTML += '<form id="myform" action="myurl.php" method="post" target="_blank"><input type="hidden" name="html_document_name"  value="'+ html_document +'"></form>';
document.getElementById("myform").submit();
```

But in `myurl.php` the `html_document` value is blank. If I try:

```
var html_document = 'test';
```

It works correctly. If i try

```
alert(html_document);
```

It works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Using a jquery specific solution as tagged, see the code below to capture your HTML.

```
var html = $("html").html();

If you want to also capture the hmtl tags you could concatenate them to the html like this:
function getPageHTML() {
  return "<html>" + $("html").html() + "</html>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your request is not completed in time because you do not wait for it. With alert it is a blocking call so it will work.

Use jquery ajax to process your request. And do your processing in the success function.

```
 $.ajax(
    {
        url: someUrl,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) { someSuccessFunction(data); },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { someErrorFunction(); }
    });
```

Comment: i received:
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://xxxxxxxxxxxx.com' is therefore not allowed access.